# Amenable groups with all subgroups finitely generated

Tags: gr.group-theory

Does anyone know an example of an amenable group with all subgroups finitely generated that is not elementary amenable?

Comment: No it's certainly unknown. (For elementary amenable groups, noetherian means virtually polycyclic, but you probably know this.) Very few noetherian groups are known: virtually polycyclic, quasi-finite f.g. groups, quasi-cyclic ones (all constructed by Olshanskii), and some immediate variants or combinations.

Comment: Such groups "probably" exist though?